# How to fix bad request (code 400) error in post request?

Tags: swift, rest, api, alamofire, http-status-code-400

I am adding an `Agreement Module` in my app, where in the user will tap the checkbox when he/she agrees. When the user tapped the checkbox it will return a `true` value and will enable the `proceed` button. Upon tapping the `proceed` button it will activate the user's account. The problem is, it returns a  `status code 400` and it does not activate the user's account.  I can't figure it out which part of my code has an error or does the error comes from the `API` side.

I tried to check it in `PostMan` using the same parameters I used in my `APIService.swift` file it returns `status code 200` and it activates the user's account.

**APIService.swift**

```
func createUser(userRole: UserRole, credential: String, email: String, secureText: String, termsConditions: Bool, completion: @escaping validateTaskCompletion) {

guard let createUserURL = URL(string: CREATE_USER_URL) else {
    completion(nil, .InvalidURL)
    return
}

let firstParameterTitle = "firstCredential"
let secondParameterTitle = "userType"
let thirdParameterTitle = "email"
let fourthParameterTitle = "password"
let fifthParameterTitle = "hasAgreedToTermsConditions"

let requestBody: Parameters = [

    firstParameterTitle: credential,
    secondParameterTitle: userRole.rawValue,
    thirdParameterTitle: email,
    fourthParameterTitle: secureText,
    fifthParameterTitle: termsConditions
]

Alamofire.request(createUserURL, method: .post, parameters: requestBody).responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) in

    guard reachability(responseResult: response.result) else {
        completion(nil, .NoNetwork)
        return
    }

    guard let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode else {
        completion(nil, .NoStatusCode)
        return
    }

    switch(statusCode) {
    case 200:
        completion(true, nil)
    case 400:
        completion(nil, .BadRequest)
    case 404:
        completion(nil, .InvalidCredentials)
    case 409:
        completion(nil, .AlreadyActivated)
    default:
        completion(nil, .UncapturedStatusCode)
        print("**createUser** Uncaptured Status Code: \(statusCode)")
    }

})
```

**TermsAndConditionVC.swift**

```
var userRole: UserRole!
var firstCredential: String!
var emailString: String!
var confirmPasswordString: String!
var agreedtoTermsConditions: Bool!

@IBAction func checkedButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if sender.isSelected {
        agreedtoTermsConditions = false
        sender.isSelected = false
        self.proceedButton.isEnabled = false

    } else {
        agreedtoTermsConditions = true
        sender.isSelected = true
       self.proceedButton.isEnabled = true

}
}

 @IBAction func proceedButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    createUser(userRole: userRole!, credential: firstCredential!, email: emailString, secureText: confirmPasswordString, termsConditions: agreedtoTermsConditions) { (success, error) in

        guard success == true, error == nil else {

            if let networkError = error {

                if networkError == .AlreadyActivated {
                    _ = SCLAlertView(appearance: appearance).showError("Already Activated", subTitle: "\(networkError.rawValue)")
                }else if networkError == .BadRequest {
                    _ = SCLAlertView(appearance: appearance).showError("Error", subTitle: "There is something went wrong. Please try again.")
                }else {
                    _ = SCLAlertView(appearance: appearance).showError("Network Error", subTitle: "\(networkError.rawValue)")
                }
            }

            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "hideLoading"), object: nil)
            return
        }

    }

    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "nextStep"), object: nil)

}
```

Comment: Does your request need any Headers, perhaps? Also, have you tried adding some form of encoding to your request?

Comment: @A.Welch I have no headers included in my code, do i have to add headers to declare the content-type?

Comment: No, you shouldn’t have too. Also, double check that all parameter names match your postman

Comment: @A.Welch all parameters are matched